# Non-uniqueness of (Galerkin) approximations and convergent subsequences without the axiom of choice?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations, axiom-of-choice, nets

Suppose I have an equation in some reflexive separable Banach space $X$:
$$Au=f$$
for given data $f$ and $A\colon X \to X^*$ a pseudo-monotone operator. Existence can be proved via Galerkin approximations where one takes a finite dimensional subspace $X_n \subset X$ and considers
$$\langle Au_n, \varphi_j \rangle = \langle f, \varphi_j\rangle \quad\forall j=1,...,n$$
where $\{\varphi_j\}_{j=1}^n$ is a basis for $X_n$ and $u_n$ is supposed to lie in the span of this basis. Fine.

Then one derives a uniform estimate like $\lVert u_n \rVert_X \leq C$ and passes to the limit. My question is the following.

Typically there is no uniqueness of solutions for the equation, nor for the Galerkin approximations. Showing that the Galerkin approximations $u_n$ exist is done by a proof of contradiction so the proof is not constructive. This means that $u_n$ is not unique and there may be uncountable many solutions for each $n$. In this case, how can we choose a sequence and then apply Banach--Alagolu to that sequence without using the axiom of choice to select an element for each $n$?

Comment: Seeing how the Banach–Alagolu theorem is equivalent to the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem, which is weaker than AC, but not provable from ZF, I don't see why you could do that. But then again, your space is separable, so it might be enough to get *some* information out of it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Even in the non-separable case, apparently it can be done through the use of nets (which I'm not familiar with at all, so I cannot say much about it). Banach-Alagolu is applied in that case too.

Comment: You asked about the axiom of choice, and I commented on that. The important of a space being separable is not that you can do things as sequences. It is that you have a well-ordering to work with.

Comment: Also, not to belabour the point, but analysis in ZF is just terrible. At the very least one should work in ZF+DC, which means you have countable choice, so you can choose an approximation for each $n$. But then, again, the hard part is using Banach–Alagolu.

Comment: Now posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [Non-uniqueness of (Galerkin) approximations and convergent subsequences without the axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/356845#comment898266_356845)